# For an arbitrary function, how can I tell if the eigenvalues are positive or negative at a critical point?

Tags: calculus

I was given the following "bonus question" on my homework. 
[image]

So I set up the determinant to find the characteristic polynomial

$$\begin{vmatrix}
f_{xx}(a,b)-\lambda & f_{xy}(a,b)\\
f_{yx}(a,b) & f_{yy}(a,b) - \lambda
\end{vmatrix} = (f_{xx}(a,b)-\lambda)(f_{xx}(a,b)-\lambda)-f_{xy}(a,b)^2= 0$$

So then

$$\lambda^2 - \lambda (f_{xx}(a,b)+f_{yy}(a,b)) + \det(Hf(a,b)) = 0$$

So I used the quadratic formula

$$\lambda = \frac{((f_{xx}(a,b)+f_{yy}(a,b))\pm \sqrt{((f_{xx}(a,b)+f_{yy}(a,b)))^2-4\det(Hf(a,b))})}{2}$$

But I don't know $f$. How can I judge whether the eigenvalues are positive or negative assuming that I know $f(a,b)$ is a specific type of critical point (e.g. local max)?

As you answer my question, if you can answer so it is applicable to an $n$ dimensional Hessian matrix, that would be ideal. I would prefer the generalized form, not just 2x2

Comment: Do you understand what eigenvectors and eigenvalues, and in particular those of symmetric real matrices, mean geometrically?

Comment: No just the algebra

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If both $\lambda$'s have the same sign, then their sum has that same sign as well.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why I don’t need to know the signs and relative magnitude of the element of the Hessian? Without that information, I do not see how to proceed.